# How do I convert an array of col-sm-3 columns into rows with 4 columns each?

Tags: reactjs

I have the below code and I'm trying to figure out how to convert the mapped array of categories into rows with four categories in each.

```
    renderCategories = () => {
        const categories = this.state.categories.map( category => {
            return (
                <div key={ category.categoryId} className="col-sm-3 card text- center" style={{margin: '10px', paddingTop: '5px'}}>
                    <h5>
                        <Link to={ `/category/${ category.categoryId }`}>{ category.name }</Link>
                    </h5>
                </div>
            )
        });
        return categories;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap renderCategories into div with class "row"

```
  renderCategories = () => {
    const categories = this.state.categories.map( category => {
        return (
            <div key={ category.categoryId} className="col-sm-3 card text- center" style={{margin: '10px', paddingTop: '5px'}}>
                <h5>
                    <Link to={ `/category/${ category.categoryId }`}>{ category.name }</Link>
                </h5>
            </div>
        )
    });
    return <div class="row">{categories}</div>;
};
```

Comment: That would create a single row with 58 col-sm-3 columns. I need to take the array of 58 columns and break it into rows of 4.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new row on every 4 columns, you could add a  conditional statement like below :

```
renderCategories = () => {
    let categories = [];
    this.state.categories.forEach((category, i) => {
        if((i+1) % 4 == 0){
            categories.push(
            <div className="row" key={category.categoryId}>       
                <div key={category.categoryId} className="col-sm-3 card text- center" style={{ margin: '10px', paddingTop: '5px' }}>
                    <h5>
                        <Link to={`/category/${category.categoryId}`}>{category.name}</Link>
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            )
        }else{
            categories.push(
                <div key={category.categoryId} className="col-sm-3 card text- center" style={{ margin: '10px', paddingTop: '5px' }}>
                    <h5>
                        <Link to={`/category/${category.categoryId}`}>{category.name}</Link>
                    </h5>
                </div>
            );
        }
    });

    return categories;
}
```

Or alternatively you could still using the whole columns in a single row by inserting a
`<div className="clearfix"></div>` on every 4 item to force the columns to wrap :

```
render() {
    let categories = [];
    this.state.categories.forEach((category, i) => {
        categories.push(
            <div key={category.categoryId} className="col-sm-3 card text- center" style={{ margin: '10px', paddingTop: '5px' }}>
                <h5>
                    <Link to={`/category/${category.categoryId}`}>{category.name}</Link>
                </h5>
            </div>
        );
        // insert full width div every 4 columns
        if ((idx + 1) % 4 === 0) { categories.push(<div className="clearfix"></div>) }
    });

    return categories;
}
```